# How to merge to a remote tag or a commit id

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-merge

I am at my local branch and need to merge my changes to an **remote** tag or a commit.

I have tried `git merge <commit-id>` and `git merge <tag-name>` from my local but it keeps saying '`Already up-to-date`' but I know it's not. I also tried `git merge origin/<commit-id>` but it said `not something we can merge`. Am I missing something here? Thanks for the help

Comment: You are trying to merge your changes into the remote side or merge the remote side into your local?

Comment: @merlin2011 trying to merge my changes into the remote side. I do have a remote branch contains my changes already though. Just don't know how to merge that to the old tag

Answer (score 3):

You need to merge your commit to a local copy of the remote branch and push it back.

- You can't merge to a tag. The difference between a tag and a branch is that you can't move the tag forward.
- You can't merge to a commit. A merge is a commit. You can merge to a branch that has a specific commit as its tip.

The rough method for updating a remote branch (specifically from the remote named origin) is this:

```
git fetch
git branch <branch-name> origin/<branch-name>
git checkout <branch-name>
git merge <commit>
git push
```

If you want to prove that you can't merge into a tag or commit, replace  with a tag or commit SHA1. You'll find yourself unable to merge.

Additionally, while I put `git merge <commit>` in that method, your really should manage merging with branches, not with individual commits.